# Pattern avoiding duplicate processing Block

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a class :

```
public class VisitorProcessing {
    public void visit(EventA eventA){
           if(condition1....)
                // Do somethings 1
           else{
               if(condition2){
               // Do something 2
               }
               else{
               // Do something 3
               }
           } 
    }
    public void visit(EventB eventB){
           if(condition1....)
                // Do somethings 4
           else{
               if(condition2){
               // Do something 5
               }
               else{
               // Do something 6
               }
           } 
    }
    public void visit(EventC eventC){
           if(condition1....)
                // Do somethings 7
           else{
               if(condition2){
               // Do something 8
               }
               else{
               // Do something 9
               }
           } 
    }
    public void visit(EventD eventD){
           if(condition1....)
                // Do somethings 10
           else{
               if(condition2){
               // Do something 11
               }
               else{
               // Do something 12
               }
           } 
    } 
}
```

All Event Object Extends the same Parent Object BasicEvent. 
And the conditions are refering only to Event Object and can be calculated from the Parent Event .

I want to start a refactoring to group the logic of branching in one place because i am not sure about the conditions . 
The only things that i am sure is the processing "DoSomthings..." .

So i am searching is there any known pattern for doing this .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are these "do something"s the same?

Comment: No the doSothings are very different

Comment: Are condition1 and condition2 the same in the 3 blocks?

Comment: Yes the conditions are the same

Comment: And my Event object are inheriting from the same Object (BasicEvent)

Comment: Two questions. 1) conditions refer to the eventA/eventB/eventC instances? 2) EventA, EventB, EventC classes have common parent calls?

Comment: Yes conditions refer to Events and EventA , EventB ..... all extends BasicEvent Object

Comment: Can't you implement the logic in the Event* classes?

Comment: No the event class are in other package and don't have the information of "what to do"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dispatch method is responsible for the correct calling of methods, you just need to write the 3 methids each time.

```
public interface DoSomething {
    void doSomething1();
    void doSomething2();
    void doSomething3();
}

public class VisitorProcessing {

    public void dispatch( DoSomething ds) {
        if(condition1....)
            ds.doSomething1();
       else{
           if(condition2){
               ds.doSomething2();
           }
           else{
               ds.doSomething3();
           }
       } 
    }

    public void visit(EventA eventA){
        DoSomething ds = new DoSomething()
        {
            void doSomething1() {
             // Do somethings 1
            }
            void doSomething2(){
             // Do something 2
            }
            void doSomething3(){
             // Do something 3
            }
        }
        dispatch( ds );
    }

    public void visit(EventB eventB){
        DoSomething ds = new DoSomething()
        {
            void doSomething1() {
             // Do somethings 3
            }
            void doSomething2(){
             // Do something 4
            }
            void doSomething3(){
             // Do something 5
            }
        }
        dispatch( ds );
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I like your pattern , i will test it . The only point that i see is that Event and DoSomthing are associated manually . We need to say EventA ==> DoSomethingA , but it's not big deal , thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the [chain-of-responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).
Essentially, you have a class `Handler` that acts based on a decision, and that contains an object of type `Handler` that can be delegated when the condition is not satisfied. Example:

```
public Class Handler() {
  private Handler next;

  public setNext(Handler next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

  public void action(params) {
    if(some_condition) {
      ...
    }
    else {
      if(next != null)
        next.action(params);
    }
  }
}
```

Naturally, the class can and should be extended to create different type of handlers. The advantage of this pattern in your case is that you could use the same chain with the same condition, and vary the action based on which `visit` method was called. Also, you can add, edit and remove conditions quite easily, and even modify the chain at runtime.

In your case:

```
public Class Condition1 extends Handler {
  public void action(BasicEvent e) {
    if (condition1) {
      if(e instanceof EventA) // Do something 1
      if(e instanceof EventB) // Do something 4
      if(e instanceof EventC) // Do something 7
      if(e instanceof EventD) // Do something 10
    }
    else {
      if(next != null)
        next.action(BasicEvent e);
    }
  }
}

public Class Condition2 extends Handler {
  public void action(BasicEvent e) {
    if (condition2) {
      if(e instanceof EventA) // Do something 2
      if(e instanceof EventB) // Do something 5
      if(e instanceof EventC) // Do something 8
      if(e instanceof EventD) // Do something 11
    }
    else {
      if(next != null)
        next.action(BasicEvent e);
    }
  }
}

public Class ConditionElse extends Handler {
  public void action(BasicEvent e) {
    if(e instanceof EventA) // Do something 3
    if(e instanceof EventB) // Do something 6
    if(e instanceof EventC) // Do something 9
    if(e instanceof EventD) // Do something 12

    // we reached the end of the chain
  }
}
```

Create similar classes for other conditions if you have them (as many as you like), then form the chain:

```
Condition1 condition_1 = new Condition1();
Condition2 condition_2 = new Condition2();
ConditionElse condition_else = new new ConditionElse();

condition_1.setNext(condition_2);
condition_2.setNext(condition_else);
```

And then you need only one `visit` method:

```
public void visit(BasicEvent e){
  condition1.action(e);
}
```

I hope I gave you a quick overview of the pattern adapted to your case. The `instanceof` part could be handled in better ways, specially if you had more than 4 subclasses it would be worth refactoring, but I hope you get the gist.

Comment: Thanks for the comment , nice insight for now i don't need all this flexibilty (Condition setNext ) and the instanceOf is real pain , that's why we implement a Visitor pattern. But for future if i have this need to change Conditions , i will test the  chain-of-responsibility pattern .

Comment: I agree StephaneM's answer is much better suited for your needs. With that solution, adding and removing classes is not a problem. With mine, adding and removing conditions could be faster. At some point you'll have to make a decision on where you want the difficult part, and I think in this case the dispatcher presented in the accepted answer is the best choice.

Comment: Actually, there might be a way to combine the two, I might post that in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the visit methods then what you can do is create a process(BasicEvent event) method that is called from within each of the visit methods.

```
public class VisitorProcessing {
    public void visit(EventA eventA){
           processEvent(eventA);
           //... EventA specific code goes here
    }
    public void visit(EventB eventB){
           processEvent(eventB);
           //... EventB specific code goes here
    }
    public void visit(EventC eventC){
           processEvent(eventC);
           //... EventC specific code goes here
    }
    public void visit(EventD eventD){
           processEvent(eventD);
           //... EventD specific code goes here
    } 

    private void processEvent(BasicEvent event) {
           if(condition1....)
                // Do somethings 10
           else{
               if(condition2){
               // Do something 11
               }
               else{
               // Do something 12
               }
           } 
    }
}
```

Comment: The specific is in the conditions

Comment: @Nabil So condition1 is different for each of the visit methods?

Comment: No the conditions is the same , but the "Do Somethings" are specific